# NodeJS async.each/parallel for dynamic array

Tags: node.js, async.js

```
a=['a','b','c'];//Dynamic array
async.each(a, function (item, callback){ 
console.log(item); // print the key

callback(); // This is final callback

}, function(err,res) {
    console.log('iterating done');
});
```

I want to execute **similar tasks for each element** of **Array a** and **i need the result for every operation** and all operations are **independent**.

Please suggest a best way it can be achieved

EDIT #1

a is an array that holds queries that needs to executed for REST API Call to Salesforce Org.
For Every Query there a HTTP Request sent , I want to save all the responses **independently**.

**NOTE:** I shouldn't change the restcallmapperapi fucntion.

**Ex:** a=['Select Id from Account'];

```
async.each(a, (val,childcallback)=>{//WIP
    restcallmapperapi(val,childcallback);
        }, (err,result)=>{
            // i want result of each callback
            });



 var restcallmapperapi=(query,callback)=>{
    var headers={
        'Content-Type':'application/json',
        'Authorization':access_token
    };
    var newOptions={
        host:instance_url,
        port:null,
        path:squery+query,
        method:'GET',
        headers:headers
    };
    //console.log('query',instance_url,newOptions.path);
    var qryObj=https.request(newOptions,function(result){
        result.setEncoding('utf-8');
        var responseString1='';
        result.on('data',function(respObj){
            responseString1+=respObj;
        });
        result.on('end',function(){
            var resp=JSON.parse(responseString1);
            console.log('respo',resp.done,resp.totalSize,resp);
            if(resp.done && resp.totalSize>0){
                callback(null,resp);
            }
            else{
                callback('error for'+query);
            }

        });
    });
    qryObj.on('error',(e)=>{
        console.log('problemquery',e);
        callback('error in query object request '+e);
    });
    qryObj.end();
};
```

EDIT #2

q=['a','b','c'];

**I need result of each and every element of the array. However in below code if REST call for 'a' fails then process is not continued**

```
  const rp = require('request-promise');

async function getData(array) {
    let results = [];
    var headers= {
        'Content-Type':'application/json',
        'Authorization':access_token
    };

    for (let item of array) {
        let newOptions={
            host:instance_url,
            port:null,
            path:squery+item,
            method:'GET',
            headers:headers
        };
        let data = await rp(newOptions);
        results.push(data);
    }
    return results;
}

let a = ['a','b','c'];  // Dynamic array

getData(a).then(allData => {
    // allData is array of results
    console.log(allData);
}).catch(err => {
    // process error here
    console.log(err);
})
```

;

Comment: If you're using asynchronous code to process each item, please show us the ACTUAL asynchronous code, not a place holder.  We can teach you a lot more by showing you specifically the best way to write your actual code (probably using promises) rather than trying to get us to rewrite some generic tutorial that's been written hundreds of times already.  If you're not using asynchronous code on each array item, then get rid of the `async` library as there is no need.  Just use `a.map()`.

Comment: You should use `async.eachSeries()`

Comment: @jfriend00 i have edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the promises, `async/await` and the `request-promise` library like this to run your requests serially, one after the other:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');

async function getData(array) {
    let results = [];
    var headers= {
        'Content-Type':'application/json',
        'Authorization':access_token
    };

    for (let item of array) {
        let newOptions={
            host:instance_url,
            port:null,
            path:squery+item,
            method:'GET',
            headers:headers
        };

        let data = await rp(newOptions).catch(e => {
            console.log(e);
            // if error, make data be null and continue processing
            return null;
        });
        results.push(data);
    }
    return results;
}

let a = ['a','b','c'];  // Dynamic array

getData(a).then(allData => {
    // allData is array of results
    console.log(allData);
}).catch(err => {
    // process error here
    console.log(err);
});
```

Or, if your array is not too long and the host you're requesting from can take lots of parallel requests, you can then run the requests in parallel like this and perhaps get a bit faster end result:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');

function getData(array) {
    var headers= {
        'Content-Type':'application/json',
        'Authorization':access_token
    };

    return Promise.all(array.map(item => {
        let newOptions={
            host:instance_url,
            port:null,
            path:squery+item,
            method:'GET',
            headers:headers
        };
        return rp(newOptions).catch(e => {
            // if error, put null into result array
            console.log(e);
            return null;
        });
    }));
}

let a = ['a','b','c'];  // Dynamic array

getData(a).then(allData => {
    // allData is array of results
    console.log(allData);
}).catch(err => {
    // process error here
    console.log(err);
})
```

---

Here's a little background on this code:

1. The `request-promise` library is a promisified version of the request library.  That means it returns a promise when the entire request is done allowing you to use promises to control your asynchronous control flow.  Promises are the Javascript design direction for managing asynchronous operations.
2. The request library is a wrapper around `http.get()` and `http.post()`, etc... that gives you a higher level interface.  In this case, what we're mostly interested in is letting it gather the entire response for us rather than making us write code to collect it.
3. In the first option, `async/await` allows us to write very simple code that serializes the requests so the 2nd one isn't sent until the first one is done.
4. In the second option, we run all the requests in parallel and let `Promise.all()` collect all the results for us in order and tell us when they are all done.

Comment: It Helped :) .Great Explanation and thanks for the module.. i am eager to explore it

Comment: whenever there is an issue with atleast one request.. i could see that the subsequent requests are not executed.

Comment: @Krishnakanthjuluru - Yes, that is the usual design with promises.  That can easily be modified, but you would have to specify what you want the behavior to be and what you want to return in that case.

Comment: @Krishnakanthjuluru - I modified both examples in my answer to keep processing if there was an error and to return `null` for that request's data.

Comment: Yeah i am able to figure out that :) . Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

**Using `async`**

```
var a=['a','b','c'];

async.map(a, function (elem, callback) {
  // for each product, update its DB entry
  console.log(elem);
  elem =elem + "H";
  callback(null, elem);
}, function (err, result) {
  // all finished
  console.log('database calls done', result);
});
```

**Using "Q" library:**

```
var the_promises = []; //Maintain an Array.

arrList.forEach(function(elem){
  var deferred = Q.defer();
  DAO.create(elem, function(err, data){
    if(err){
       deferred.reject(err); // Reject if error.
    }else{
      deferred.resolve(data); // Resolve promises.
    }
    the_promises.push(deferred.promise); // Push promises to the array.
  });
});

Q.all(the_promises).then(function(values) { // When all promises done you will be here with all element output in the array.
  console.log(values[0]);
  console.log(values[1]);
}, function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```